# How can I send an image editing request to the OpenAI endpoint from an Android App written in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, openai-api

I'm new to Android development and I want to create an app that makes use of the OpenAI API. This is my first time using APIs and HTTP. The most important feature uses a photo taken by the user's camera and a custom prompt to edit it using the v1/images/edits endpoint. I'm having a hard time sending the request because every time I get an error. The biggest confusion I have is how to send the image.

I've tried using community libraries, but they are buggy and don't seem to be updated very often. I've tried sending the request with Retrofit, but the way I send the image seems to be the problem, I get a 415 code as response.

```
    fun editImage(){
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://api.openai.com")
            .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        val openAi = retrofit.create(OpenAI::class.java)

        val txtRequest = "A giant mice with a hat"
        val requestBody = EditRequest(
            image = FilePath(imgUri.value.toString()),
            prompt = txtRequest)


        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val response = openAi.sendImageRequest(API_KEY, requestBody)
                Log.i("URL", response.toString())
            } catch (e: Exception){
                Log.e("Exception", e.toString())
            }
        }
    }
```

```
    @POST("/v1/images/edits")
    suspend fun sendImageRequest(
        @Header("Authorization") apiKey: String,
        @Body request: EditRequest
    ): EditResponse
```

Maybe uploading the official OpenAI Python or Node.js code to a serverless solution could be an option, but I think that's too much. Thank you for your time :)

Comment: Can you add the error message you're getting?